# Why can't root manage Virtualbox VMs created by vboxuser?

Tags: debian, virtualbox

My host is running Debian Stretch. I have 3 VMs that are owned by `vboxuser`, a member of `vboxusers` group. As root, I cannot get any output from `vboxmanage list vms`. If I `su -s/bin/bash - vboxuser`, then I can run the command.

I understand that it needs to have permissions to manage the VMs, and that's why we have the `vboxusers` group. However, root cannot! As a test, I added root to that group, and root still cannot view VMs in Virtualbox.

Is there a known way to accomplish this?

Comment: Run `vboxmanage list systemproperties` as both `vboxuser` and `root`.  You will probably find that `root` is searching a different directory for the VirtualBox VMs to list than is `vboxuser`.  ("Default machine folder" in the systemproperties output)

Comment: You're right, they're different! Is there a way I can move root's `Default machine Folder` to the one currently in use?